# How to add type-tolerance configuration setting in Algolia react-instantsearch for react-native application?

Tags: react-native, algolia, react-instantsearch

I am new to react-native. How to implement Algolia instant search in react native project?

Answer (score 0):

As with any project that wants to use Algolia for search, you first need to push your data to your index. This can be done in any programming language (JavaScript, Ruby, etc) by using the official Algolia API Clients. This step is either a one-time thing (if your data does not change), or something that should be kept in sync with your database (if your data is updated often).

The second part is to build the front-end to search into this data. As you're using React Native, you should use React InstantSearch (https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/) for that. It provides all the UI widgets you'll need to build the search interface.